# Wait for the async callback function to return in java

Tags: java, asynccallback

```
final Function<Boolean, ? extends Class<Void>> functionCallback = (Boolean t) -> {
   if(t) {
     plugin.setIsInstalled(Boolean.TRUE);             
   }
   return Void.TYPE;
};

foo.install(plugin,functionCallback);

if(plugin.getIsInstalled().getValue())
  return "done";
else 
  return "not done";
```

I want to check `if(plugin.getIsInstalled().getValue())` once the callback has finished executing. How can I prevent execution of this if condition until callback has completed execution?

Comment: What is the return type of `getIsInstalled`?

Comment: BooleanProperty of javafx package. This property is set inside callback function which I want to access once callback has finished execution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `FutureTask` that gets called in your callback function:

```
final FutureTask<Object> ft = new FutureTask<Object>(() -> {}, new Object());
final Function<Boolean, ? extends Class<Void>> functionCallback = (Boolean t) -> {
    if(t) {
        plugin.setIsInstalled(Boolean.TRUE);
        ft.run();
    }
    return Void.TYPE;
};

foo.install(plugin,functionCallback); 
ft.get();
if(plugin.getIsInstalled().getValue())
    return "done";
else 
    return "not done";
```

`Future.get` waits till the `run` method was called, you can also use the `get`-method that accepts a timeout so you can react on that if it takes too long.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use a `CountDownLatch` or a `ReentrantLock` that gets released when the function is run.
2. Your `foo#install` can return a `CompletableFuture` and you can consume the results as follows

```java
CompletableFuture<Integer> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 1);
future.thenAccept((v) -> System.out.println("v = " + v));
```

3. Function itself has an `andThen` method which you can use to run whatever is required post `apply`.

Answer (score -1):

The callback is mostly used to perform a task after a particular task is done. So it better separate the code you want to execute into a different function call that function.

If you want to execute something after callback have nested callbacks.